# Xpages: send html email via java using backend document

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I found this great Java Bean that allows you to send an html email including attachments via a [managed java bean](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter). It works as described when I use it directly form an Xpage.

However, I would like to use this in the backend in a scheduled agent. The problem I have run into is when I try to pass a document to the java bean. The bean is expecting (I think) an XSP document, which I don't have when in the back end, so it throws an error.

I thought I would just send the UNID of the document that I want and then change it so it would work with this bean, however, when I try to set the UNID I get an error:

```
Unknown member 'setUNID' in Java class 'com.scoular.utls.Email'
```

I am confused. Seems like this has something to do with a wrapped document, but don't understand.

Here is the faces-config:

```
<faces-config>
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>Email</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.scoular.utls.Email</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
    <managed-property>
      <property-name>debugMode</property-name>
      <value>true</value>
    </managed-property>
  </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

Here is a button I am using to test calling the method:

```
//Need to get email document 
var emlView = database.getView("xpViewEmailsAll");
var emlDoc = emlView.getFirstDocument();
if (emlDoc != null) {


//try{
    var subject = ""       
    var senderEmail = supEml
    var senderName = supNme

    Email.setSendTo("John");
    Email.setSubject("subject");
    Email.setSenderEmail("John@gmal.com");
    Email.setUNID = emlDoc.getUniversalID();
    Email.setSenderName("Sender");
    //Email.setBackEndDocument(emlDoc);
    Email.setFieldName("Body");
    Email.send();
//}catch(e){
    //print(e.getMessage());
//}
}
```

And here is the bean:

```
package com.scoular.utls;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.Document;
import lotus.domino.EmbeddedObject;
import lotus.domino.MIMEEntity;
import lotus.domino.MIMEHeader;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.Session;
import lotus.domino.Stream;

import com.ibm.commons.util.NotImplementedException;
import com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext;
import com.ibm.xsp.model.FileRowData;
import com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument;
import com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoRichTextItem;
import com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.wrapped.DominoDocument.AttachmentValueHolder;
import com.ibm.xsp.persistence.PersistedContent;

public class Email {

    private ArrayList<String> sendTo;
    private ArrayList<String> ccList;
    private ArrayList<String> bccList;
    private String senderEmail;
    private String senderName;
    private String subject;
    private DominoDocument document;
    private String fieldName;
    private String bannerHTML;
    private String footerHTML;
    private String unid;
    private boolean debugMode = false;
    private static final Pattern imgRegExp = Pattern.compile("<img[^>]+src\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>");

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public Email() {
        this.subject = "";
        this.sendTo = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.ccList = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.bccList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getSendTo() {
        if (this.isDebugMode()) {
            System.out.println("getSendTo() : " + this.sendTo.toString());
        }
        return this.sendTo.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    }

    public void setSendTo(final String sendTo) {
        this.sendTo.add(sendTo);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getCcList() {
        if (this.isDebugMode()) {
            System.out.println("getCcList() : " + this.ccList.toString());
        }
        return this.ccList.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    }

    public void setCcList(final String ccList) {
        this.ccList.add(ccList);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getBccList() {
        if (this.isDebugMode()) {
            System.out.println("getBccList() : " + this.bccList.toString());
        }
        return this.bccList.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
    }

    public void setBccList(final String bccList) {
        this.bccList.add(bccList);
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getSenderEmail() {
        return this.senderEmail;
    }

    public void setSenderEmail(final String senderEmail) {
        this.senderEmail = senderEmail;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getSenderName() {
        return this.senderName;
    }

    public void setSenderName(final String senderName) {
        this.senderName = senderName;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getSubject() {
        return this.subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(final String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public boolean isDebugMode() {
        return this.debugMode;
    }

    public void setDebugMode(final boolean debugMode) {
        this.debugMode = debugMode;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private Session getCurrentSession() {
        NotesContext nc = NotesContext.getCurrentUnchecked();
        return (null != nc) ? nc.getCurrentSession() : null;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private Database getCurrentDatabase() {
        NotesContext nc = NotesContext.getCurrentUnchecked();
        return (null != nc) ? nc.getCurrentDatabase() : null;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void send() throws NotesException, IOException, Exception {
        Session session = getCurrentSession();
        Database database = getCurrentDatabase();
        if (null != session && null != database && null != this.sendTo && null != this.subject
                && null != this.senderEmail) {
            try {
                if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                    System.out.println("Started send()");
                }
                session.setConvertMime(false);
                Document emailDocument = database.createDocument();

                MIMEEntity emailRoot = emailDocument.createMIMEEntity("Body");
                if (null != emailRoot) {
                    MIMEHeader emailHeader = emailRoot.createHeader("Reply-To");
                    emailHeader.setHeaderVal(this.getSenderEmail());

                    emailHeader = emailRoot.createHeader("Return-Path");
                    emailHeader.setHeaderVal(this.getSenderEmail());

                    final String fromSender = (null == this.getSenderName()) ? this.getSenderEmail() : "\""
                            + this.getSenderName() + "\" <" + this.getSenderEmail() + ">";

                    emailHeader = emailRoot.createHeader("From");
                    emailHeader.setHeaderVal(fromSender);

                    emailHeader = emailRoot.createHeader("Sender");
                    emailHeader.setHeaderVal(fromSender);

                    emailHeader = emailRoot.createHeader("To");
                    emailHeader.setHeaderVal(this.getSendTo());

                    if (!this.ccList.isEmpty()) {
                        emailHeader = emailRoot.createHeader("CC");
                        emailHeader.setHeaderVal(this.getCcList());
                    }

                    if (!this.bccList.isEmpty()) {
                        emailHeader = emailRoot.createHeader("BCC");
                        emailHeader.setHeaderVal(this.getBccList());
                    }

                    emailHeader = emailRoot.createHeader("Subject");
                    emailHeader.setHeaderVal(this.getSubject());

                    MIMEEntity emailRootChild = emailRoot.createChildEntity();
                    if (null != emailRootChild) {
                        final String boundary = System.currentTimeMillis() + "-" + this.document.getDocumentId();
                        emailHeader = emailRootChild.createHeader("Content-Type");
                        emailHeader.setHeaderVal("multipart/alternative; boundary=\"" + boundary + "\"");

                        MIMEEntity emailChild = emailRootChild.createChildEntity();
                        if (null != emailChild) {
                            final String contentAsText = this.document.getRichTextItem(this.fieldName)
                                    .getContentAsText();
                            Stream stream = session.createStream();
                            stream.writeText(contentAsText);
                            emailChild.setContentFromText(stream, "text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"", MIMEEntity.ENC_NONE);
                            stream.close();

                            emailChild = emailRootChild.createChildEntity();
                            stream = session.createStream();
                            stream.writeText(this.getHTML());
                            emailChild.setContentFromText(stream, "text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"", MIMEEntity.ENC_NONE);
                            stream.close();
                            stream.recycle();
                            stream = null;
                        }

                        // add embedded images....
                        final List<FileRowData> embeddedImages = this.getEmbeddedImagesList();
                        if (null != embeddedImages && !embeddedImages.isEmpty()) {
                            if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                                System.out.println("Adding Embedded Images...");
                            }
                            for (FileRowData embeddedImage : embeddedImages) {
                                emailRootChild = emailRoot.createChildEntity();
                                if (null != emailRootChild && embeddedImage instanceof AttachmentValueHolder) {
                                    InputStream is = null;
                                    try {
                                        String persistentName = ((AttachmentValueHolder) embeddedImage)
                                                .getPersistentName();
                                        String cid = ((AttachmentValueHolder) embeddedImage).getCID();
                                        emailHeader = emailRootChild.createHeader("Content-Disposition");
                                        emailHeader.setHeaderVal("inline; filename=\"" + persistentName + "\"");
                                        emailHeader = emailRootChild.createHeader("Content-ID");
                                        emailHeader.setHeaderVal("<" + cid + ">");
                                        is = this.getEmbeddedImageStream(persistentName);
                                        Stream stream = session.createStream();
                                        stream.setContents(is);
                                        emailRootChild.setContentFromBytes(stream, embeddedImage.getType(),
                                                MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY);
                                        if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                                            System.out.println("Added Embedded Image : " + persistentName);
                                        }
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                                            System.out.println("Adding Embedded Image failed : " + e.getMessage());
                                        }
                                        throw e;
                                    } finally {
                                        if (null != is) {
                                            is.close();
                                            is = null;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                                System.out.println("Completed Adding Embedded Images");
                            }
                        }

                        // add attachments....
                        final List<FileRowData> attachments = this.getDocument().getAttachmentList(this.getFieldName());
                        if (null != attachments && !attachments.isEmpty()) {
                            if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                                System.out.println("Adding Attachments...");
                            }
                            for (FileRowData attachment : attachments) {
                                emailRootChild = emailRoot.createChildEntity();
                                if (null != emailRootChild && attachment instanceof AttachmentValueHolder) {
                                    InputStream is = null;
                                    try {
                                        String persistentName = ((AttachmentValueHolder) attachment)
                                                .getPersistentName();
                                        String cid = ((AttachmentValueHolder) attachment).getCID();
                                        EmbeddedObject eo = this.getDocument().getDocument().getAttachment(
                                                persistentName);
                                        if (null != eo) {
                                            emailHeader = emailRootChild.createHeader("Content-Disposition");
                                            emailHeader.setHeaderVal("attachment; filename=\"" + persistentName + "\"");
                                            emailHeader = emailRootChild.createHeader("Content-ID");
                                            emailHeader.setHeaderVal("<" + cid + ">");
                                            is = eo.getInputStream();
                                            Stream stream = session.createStream();
                                            stream.setContents(is);
                                            emailRootChild.setContentFromBytes(stream, attachment.getType(),
                                                    MIMEEntity.ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY);
                                            if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                                                System.out.println("Added Attachment : " + persistentName);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                                            System.out.println("Adding Attachment failed : " + e.getMessage());
                                        }
                                        throw e;
                                    } finally {
                                        if (null != is) {
                                            is.close();
                                            is = null;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                                System.out.println("Completed Adding Attachments");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                emailDocument.send();
                session.setConvertMime(true);
                if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                    System.out.println("Completed send()");
                }
            } catch (NotesException e) {
                if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                    System.out.println("Failed send() with NotesException" + e.getMessage());
                }
                throw e;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                    System.out.println("Failed send() with IOException" + e.getMessage());
                }
                throw e;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                    System.out.println("Failed send() with Exception" + e.getMessage());
                }
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public DominoDocument getDocument() {
        return this.document;
    }

    public void setDocument(final DominoDocument document) {
        this.document = document;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getFieldName() {
        return this.fieldName;
    }

    public void setFieldName(final String fieldName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public List<FileRowData> getEmbeddedImagesList() throws NotesException {
        if (null != document && null != fieldName) {
            return document.getEmbeddedImagesList(fieldName);
        }
        return null;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private InputStream getEmbeddedImageStream(final String fileName) throws NotesException, IOException {
        if (null != document && null != fieldName && null != fileName) {
            final DominoRichTextItem drti = document.getRichTextItem(fieldName);
            if (null != drti) {
                final PersistedContent pc = drti.getPersistedContent(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), fieldName,
                        fileName);
                if (null != pc) {
                    return pc.getInputStream();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getHTML() {
        StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();
        html.append(getBannerHTML());
        html.append(getBodyHTML());
        html.append(getFooterHTML());
        return html.toString();
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getBannerHTML() {
        return this.bannerHTML;
    }

    public void setBannerHTML(final String bannerHTML) {
        this.bannerHTML = bannerHTML;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getBodyHTML() {
        if (null != document && null != fieldName) {
            if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                System.out.println("Started getBodyHTML()");
            }
            final DominoRichTextItem drti = document.getRichTextItem(fieldName);
            if (null != drti) {
                try {
                    String html = drti.getHTML();
                    if (null != html) {
                        final List<FileRowData> fileRowDataList = document.getEmbeddedImagesList(fieldName);
                        if (null != fileRowDataList) {
                            final Matcher matcher = imgRegExp.matcher(html);
                            while (matcher.find()) {
                                String src = matcher.group();
                                final String srcToken = "src=\"";
                                final int x = src.indexOf(srcToken);
                                final int y = src.indexOf("\"", x + srcToken.length());
                                final String srcText = src.substring(x + srcToken.length(), y);
                                for (FileRowData fileRowData : fileRowDataList) {
                                    final String srcImage = fileRowData.getHref();
                                    final String cidImage = ((AttachmentValueHolder) fileRowData).getCID();
                                    if (srcText.endsWith(srcImage)) {
                                        final String newSrc = src.replace(srcText, "cid:" + cidImage);
                                        html = html.replace(src, newSrc);
                                        if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                                            System.out.println("CID referenced image: " + srcText + " with CID:"
                                                    + cidImage);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                        System.out.println("Completed getBodyHTML() : " + html);
                    }
                    return html;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                        System.out.println("Failed getBodyHTML() : " + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void setBodyHTML(final String bodyHTML) throws NotImplementedException {
        if (this.isDebugMode()) {
            System.out.println("Method setBodyHTML(string) is not permitted");
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public String getFooterHTML() {
        return this.footerHTML;
    }

    public void setFooterHTML(final String footerHTML) {
        this.footerHTML = footerHTML;
    }

    public String getUnid() {
        return unid;
    }

    public void setUnid(final String unid) {
        this.unid = unid;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

} // end EmailBean
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Email.setUNID statement is wrong. Try:

```
Email.setUnid(emlDoc.getUniversalID());
```

Comment: That is a very good catch. Oddly though when I fixed this error I got an error   Cannot assign a value to method 'setUNID' in Java class 'com.scoular.utls.Email'   I removed Final and still got this message.

Comment: The method is called setUnid and not setUNID. Is that why?

Comment: Per, no I was able to get the method call's signature to work - it just doesn't like the value. Very odd.